# how to create a data frame based on the mathematical operation on another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R, in which I have year-wise transaction data for multiple individuals. I want a new data frame in which I want columns based on some conditions like the total revenue for an individual every year in a particular category.
for example

```
ID  year  a  b  c  d
1   2015  2  4  6  8
1   2015  4  6  8  10
1   2016  7  6  9  5
2   2015  7  5  6  2
2   2016  3  4  5  2
```

I want a data frame
I get a column with total values for ID 1 in 2015, ID 1 in 2016, ID 2 in 2015 and so on. and I wanted to add another condition also like total only for those columns which have a value greater than 5 for column a.

please give your suggestions... any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please share what the expected output would look like.

Comment: look into the dplyr package, especially the functions group_by, mutate and summarise

Comment: Could you please clarify what you meant by *"and I wanted to add another condition also like total only for those columns which have a value greater than 5 for column a."*

Comment: I mean I want sum of column a for id 1, year 2015 and values greater than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your question, I used the package dplyr which is incredibly helpful if you don't already have it.

First group, your data by ID and then year. Then create sums for your 4 columns based on these groupings:

```
mydata <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,2,2),
                     "year" = c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016),
                     "a" = c(2,4,7,7,3),
                     "b" = c(4,6,6,5,4),
                     "c" = c(6,8,9,6,5),
                     "d" = c(8, 10, 5, 2, 2))

mydata %>% group_by(ID, year) %>% summarise(a = sum(a), b = sum(b),
                                            c = sum(c), d = sum(d))
```

To only calculate sums greater than 5, simply specify that in the 'summaries' portion as follows:

```
mydata %>% group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  summarise(a = sum(a[a > 5]), b = sum(b[b > 5]),
            c = sum(c[c > 5]), d = sum(d[d > 5]))
```

I hope this helps!